# Finding the stationary value of a linear recurrence

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

I encountered the following recurrence when I was analyzing a problem in probability theory:

$$
a_{n}=\frac{ a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}+a_{n-5}+a_{n-6} }{6},
$$

with $a_{-5}=a_{-4}=a_{-3}=a_{-2}=a_{-1}=0$ and $a_0=1$. Now because the $a_i$ have an interpretation as probabilities (when tossing a fair die, $a_i$ is the probability the total tally will be $i$ at some point, for non-negative $i$ that is) I can prove that $a_i$ tends to $2/7$ for large $i$.

However I fail to see how to prove this fact "directly", i.e. without taking recourse to a combinatorial/probabilistic interpretation. Surely there must be a way though. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/978084/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2292035/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!