# Limit of sequence in which each term is the average of its preceding k terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

[Limit of sequence in which each term is defined by the average of preceding two terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276402/limit-of-sequence-in-which-each-term-is-defined-by-the-average-of-preceding-two)

There are answers in the link above which show methods on finding this limit and are relatively easy to generalise, when specified a $k$. However, when attempting to generalise for any $k$, it gets extremely messy with sigma notation after a few steps of incorporating, let's say, Arnaldo's method. Is there a more elegant way to prove:

For a given $u_1, u_2, ... u_k$ and that the n<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence $u_n$ is the average of its previous $k$ terms,

$$ u_n = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k}{u_{n-i}} $$

the limit of $u_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} {iu_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i}} = \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{k} {iu_i} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear recursion relationship. The methods for calculating formulas for the $n$ term are well known. In particular, we can form a vector for $k$ adjacent elements of the sequence: $$U_i = \begin{bmatrix}u_{i+k}\\u_{i+k-1}\\\vdots\\u_i\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we find that $$U_{i+1} = AU_i$$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 1k & \frac 1k & \frac 1k & \dots & \frac 1k \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0&0&0&\dots & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

And more generally $U_{n+1} = A^nU_1$. If $A$ can be diagonalized, then there exist matrices $Q, Q^{-1}, D$ with $D$ having only diagonal entries (the eigenvalues of $A$) such that $A = QDQ^{-1}$. And therefore
$$U_{n+1} = QD^nQ^{-1}U_0$$
If $$D = \begin{bmatrix}a_k & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & a_{k-1} & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0&0&\dots & a_1\end{bmatrix}$$
which I'll abbreviate to $D = [[a_k  \dots a_1 ]]$, then $D^n = [[a_k^n  \dots a_1^n ]]$. So $$U_{n+1} = Q[[a_k^n  \dots a_1^n ]]Q^{-1}U_1$$

Now the expression $Q[[a_k^n  \dots a_1^n ]]Q^{-1}U_1$ depends linearly on each of the $a_k^n$. In particular, there exist constants $B_i$ such that $$u_n = B_1a_1^n + B_2a_2^n + \dots + B_ka_k^n$$
The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $$x^k - \frac 1k\left(x^{k-1} + ... + x + 1\right)$$
so the eigenvalues $a_i$ are its roots. It is easily checked that the first root is $a_1 = 1$. And a look at the derivative shows that $1$ is not a multiple root. I'll leave determining the other roots to you. If they are distinct, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Once the eigenvalues are determined, it is not necessary to figure out $Q$. Instead you can solve the system of equations formed by $$u_n = B_1a_1^n + B_2a_2^n + \dots + B_ka_k^n$$
when $n =1 \dots k$ for the constants $B_i$.

Now taking the limit $$\lim u_n = B_1\lim a_1^n + B_2\lim a_2^n + \dots + B_k\lim a_k^n$$

Provided the limits on the right-hand side converge. Since the eigenvalues may be complex, we have $4$ cases:

- $|a_i| < 1$, in which case $\lim_n a_i^n = 0$.
- $a_i = 1$, in which case $\lim_n a_i^n = 1$.
- $|a_i| = 1$ and $a_i \ne 1$, in which case $\lim_n a_i^n$ does not converge.
- $|a_i| > 1$, in which case $\lim_n a_i^n = \infty$.

For your supposition to be correct, the limit must converge to a finite value, which means you will need to show that for $i> 1, |a_i| < 1$. In this case, $$\lim u_n = B_1$$so you will also need to show that $B_1$ has the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalization of Arnaldo's solution https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2276419/774987.

$$ku_{k+1}=u_k+u_{k-1}+...+u_1$$
$$ku_{k+2}=u_{k+1}+u_{k}+...+u_2$$
$$ku_{k+3}=u_{k+2}+u_{k+1}+...+u_3$$
$$...$$
$$ku_{n-1}=u_{n-2}+u_{n-3}+...+u_{n-(k+2)}$$
$$ku_{n}=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+...+u_{n-(k+1)}$$

Add all equations side by side and we'll get:
$$ku_n+(k-1)u_{n-1}+...+2u_{n-(k-1)}+u_{n-k}=ku_k+(k-1)u_{k-1}+...+2u_2+u_1$$

Supposing that $u_n$ has a limit L then making $n→∞$ we get:
$$(k+(k-1)+...+2+1)L=ku_k+(k-1)u_{k-1}+...+2u_2+u_1$$
$$L = \frac {ku_k+(k-1)u_{k-1}+...+2u_2+u_1}{k+(k-1)+...+2+1}$$
$$L = \frac{2}{k(k+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{k} {iu_i} $$