# Let $T_1 = 1$, $T_2 = 2$ and $T_n = (T_{n−1} + T_{n−2})/2$ when $n ≥ 3$. Find a closed form expression for $T_n$ that applies when $n ≥ 3.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form

Having trouble finding a closed form expression that applies for all $n$. I tried looking at $T_3, T_4, T_5,$ and $T_6$ to see some pattern but found none. Is there a kind of trick for these problems?

Comment: There a re several answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276402/limit-of-sequence-in-which-each-term-is-defined-by-the-average-of-preceding-two) that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve such a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) is to find roots of the characteristic equation,

which in this case is $x^2=(x+1)/2$, so the roots are $1$ and $-\frac12$,

so $T_n=A+B\left(-\frac12\right)^n$.  Use the fact that $T_1=1$ and $T_2=2$ to solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Can I use T1 = 1 and T2 = 2 even though the equation I'm trying to find only applies to n ≥ 3?

Comment: Yes, it will apply to the initial conditions as well